# What are some applications of the Morse inequalities?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, morse-theory

I'm currently learning some Morse theory, and I've just learned about the Morse inequalities. They appear to be very powerful - being able to deduce so much topological information from a single real valued function on the manifold is pretty mindblowing.

That being said, I haven't managed to find any interesting corollaries or applications of the Morse inequalities (beyond obvious calculations like, any Morse function on a torus must have at least 4 critical points etc). I realise this question is very open, but are people familiar with any results that either crucially use the Morse inequalities, or become much easier to prove using the Morse inequalities?

Comment: maybe they arent useful